# Explicit Tree in XML

Tags: xml

At work, I've come across an intensely weirdly-structured XML file. I'd like to see if this isn't actually weird-- if it's some XML idiom that I'm not familiar with that has some hidden advantage that I'm not seeing.

The XML file represents a hierarchy of parameters for an embedded system. The purpose of encoding this hierarchy in XML is to use XSL transforms to generate code and supporting documentation.  That's not the weird part.

Suppose we have the following hierarchy:

```
[Ethernet]
    MAC
    IP
[CodeType]
    foo
    bar
    [Deeper]
        bleep
        bloop
        [StillDeeper]
            thing
[Serial]
    baud
```

Obviously this isn't the actual hierarchy in the device; the real one has over 600 parameters.  In this diagram, I'm just trying to get across the idea that we have containers (the items in square brackets) and parameters (the other items). And it's hopefully equally obvious that folders can nest.

If *I* wanted to express this in XML, I would write something like this:

```xml
<db>
    <folder name="Ethernet">
        <param name="MAC"/>
        <param name="IP"/>
    </folder>
    <folder name="CodeType">
        <param name="foo"/>
        <param name="bar"/>
        <folder name="Deeper">
            <param name="bleep"/>
            <param name="bloop"/>
            <folder name="StillDeeper">
                <param name="thing"/>
            </folder>
        </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder name="Serial">
        <param name="baud"/>
    </folder>
</db>
```

And I'll bet that most everyone else would write the same thing. Putting aside the verbosity of XML, it's pretty much the same as the text example above. But that's not how the XML file I'm dealing with is actually structured. This is:

```xml
<item type="db" name="db">
    <item type="folder" name="Ethernet">
        <next>
            <item type="param" name="MAC">
                <next>
                    <item type="param" name="IP">
                    </item>
                </next>
            </item>
        </next>
        <sameLevelNext>
            <item type="folder" name="CodeType">
                <next>
                    <item type="param" name="foo">
                        <next>
                            <item type="param" name="bar">
                                <next>
                                    <item type="folder" name="Deeper">
                                        <next>
                                            <item type="param" name="bleep">
                                                <next>
                                                    <item type="param" name="bloop">
                                                        <next>
                                                            <item type="folder" name="StillDeeper">
                                                                <next>
                                                                    <item type="param" name="thing">
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </next>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </next>
                                                    </item>
                                                </next>
                                            </item>
                                        </next>
                                    </item>
                                </next>
                            </item>
                        </next>
                    </item>
                </next>
            </item>
            <sameLevelNext>
                <item type="folder" name="Serial">
                    <next>
                        <item type="param" name="baud">
                        </item>
                    </next>
                </item>
            </sameLevelNext>
        </sameLevelNext>
    </item>
</item>
```

It may not be apparent, but this is (essentially) the same data structure. The most obvious difference is that instead of using XML's built-in notions of sequence and element nesting, you see a weird explicit tree structure ("next" is the next item in sequence and "sameLevelNext" is the next folder in the sequence).

This XML is transformed into code and documentation with XSL. In order for this to happen, the XSL has to recursively walk the "next" and "sameLevelNext" branches. It works, but it's far more painful than it needs to be.

It actually gets worse, but I'll spare you the gory details. Some of the parameter values are enumerations and the representation for enumerated values are lists, structured the same way as above, with a different "next" element.

So, is this replacement for sequence and element nesting something that represents some idiom in XML?  Has anyone ever seen anything quite like this in XML? I'm strongly tempted to transform this into a more canonical form and rewrite the XSL.  But if there is something terribly clever or useful lurking here, I'd like to know.

Comment: No there's nothing terribly useful or clever here. My guess is that someone just generated it in the way that involved applying the least possible number of brain cycles.

Comment: Studying the rest of the code in the system, my guess now is the person who came up with this probably started with this kind of data structure in C, and then just reimplemented it in XML.